# I start with a "he” and end the same

Tags: riddle

My co-worker came up with this cute little riddle and I thought I might share it with you.

*I start with a "he" and end the same*
*You can't miss me, as I'll drive you insane*

**What am I?**

Comment: are the quotes like this for a reason?

Comment: @lois6b, that's caused by my keyboard layout.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Perhaps the word you have in mind is

> HEADACHE.

(I'd explain how it fits the clues but it's kinda obvious.)

Possibly relevant link (spoilered because arguably the URL gives a thing or two away):

> http://susam.in/blog/adac-and-he-puzzles-from-geb/

(The original content at the far end of the link is not terribly interesting; what's relevant is the snippets quoted from *Gödel, Escher, Bach*.)

Comment: As expected, this was solved very fast! I'll accept your answer when I can.

Comment: If you expected this response time, you knew it was easy

Comment: It would have been even faster, but the first version of my answer was auto-rejected for being too short :-).

Comment: @lois6b why did you edit my answer to change the capitalization?

Comment: I think is not necessary all caps up. pardon me, change it back

Comment: I think it is clearer when the puzzle involves the individual letters as well as the meaning of the word. I capitalized the letters on purpose.

Comment: (I already did change it back.)

Comment: At first, I thought the answer was actually just "He" :D

Comment: And here I was expecting something like [He-Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/He-Man) or hehe.

Comment: The (single-ended) dialogue in GEB that I linked to does indeed (implicitly) propose HE as an answer to the question there, but with the bit about being driven insane the longer answer is necessary :-).

Comment: "Tell me, where is fancy bred? Or in the heart or in the head?" I think both alternatives fit as answers.